# ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: "" when adding a schema on systems including CentOS6

Tags: ldap

I am trying to add the schema pwm.schema to ldap and getting  below error.

Command:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/pwm.schema
```

Output:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""
```

The file contents are below:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.2.2010.04.16.1 NAME 'pwmEventLog'
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.2.2010.04.16.2 NAME 'pwmResponseSet'
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.2.2010.04.16.3 NAME 'pwmLastPwdUpdate'
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.2.2010.04.16.4 NAME 'pwmGUID'
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.1.2010.04.16.1 NAME 'pwmUser'
        AUXILIARY
        MAY ( dstPwdUpdate $ pwmEventLog $ pwmResponseSet $ pwmGUID
        ))
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem, it turned out that at some stage LDAP either tightened or changed the syntax.

The error message is unfortunately misleading.

You need to have a colon (`:`) character after `attributetype`

For example:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.2.2010.04.16.1 NAME 'pwmEventLog'
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 )
```

Needs to become:

```
attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.591242.2.2010.04.16.1 NAME 'pwmEventLog'
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 )
```

(etc)

I just tested this now on CentOS 6, I had to change a file that worked fine on CentOS5.
I don't know which other distro upgrades might be affected.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem (at first). I also found that the closing `)` must be on the same line.  If it's on the next line by itself that's also a syntax error, though the message is next to useless.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `=` with `:`
for ex:

```
cn=cn1,dc=example,dc=com
cn=cn2
```

while adding above, will give error message as

> ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""

then replace it as mentioned above:

```
cn:cn1,dc:example,dc:com
cn:cn2
```

Now run the ladpadd command

Answer (score 0):

Most probably an edge case, but I had the same error message with an ldif file generated with PowerShell. After hours of fruitless search I noticed that the file was stored as UTF-16. Converted it to UTF-8 and it worked.

```ps
$ldif | Out-File -FilePath $ldifFile -Encoding utf8
```